# Flutter Admob without Firebase project

Tags: flutter, admob, firebase-admob

I am new to Flutter and experimenting around on how to ad Admob ads in Flutter applications, found firebase_admob package, but according to the documentation we are required to create a Firebase project for that, is there any way to integrate Admob without actually crating a hole Firebase project for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually you dont need to create a firebase project to use admob.

your ads widget in flutter require adUnitId parameter.

***example for BannerAd widget***

`adUnitId: YOUR_AD_ID //for real device`

`adUnitId: BannerAd.testAdUnitId //for test in emulator`

**So you need to create a admob project in https://admob.google.com/**

after that you will get adUnitId to use in your real device

Comment: I saw a video from google where the guy states exactly that, however the documentation of firebase_admob package states that a project and json file are required, wich is confusing, so i should just go with firebase_admob package directly.

Comment: Use flutter_admob instead of firebase_admob

Comment: iOS app crashes when `GoogleService-Info.plist` is missing. Seems like you need to setup the project after all.

Comment: just use flutter_admob

Comment: You can use this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads). I have just written a detailed blog post on how to set up AdMob ads in Flutter apps.
[check it out.](https://yassinebenkhay.com/how-to-integrate-admob-ads-in-flutter/)